# onload not working in a class

Tags: javascript, class, canvas, onload

Here's my code (sorry it's long):

```js
class Vec {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Enemy {
  constructor() {
    this.pos = new Vec;
    this.vel = new Vec;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.onload = () => {
      this.image.width /= 4;
      this.image.height /= 4;
    }
    this.image.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/scribblenauts/images/8/8d/Steel_Spike.png/revision/latest?cb=20130105173440";
    this.pos.x = WIDTH;
    this.pos.y = HEIGHT - GROUND_Y - this.image.height;
  }
}

// setup
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

const WIDTH = 600;
const HEIGHT = 400;
const GROUND_Y = 50;

let enemies = [];

let lastUpdate = 0;

function update(dt, now) {
  // create enemy
  if (now - lastUpdate > 2000) {
    lastUpdate = now;
    enemies.push(new Enemy);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    // update enemy
    enemies[i].vel.x = -300;
    enemies[i].pos.x += enemies[i].vel.x * dt;

    if (enemies[i].pos.x + enemies[i].image.width < 0)
      enemies.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

function draw() {
  // draw background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  // draw ground
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
  ctx.fillRect(0, HEIGHT - GROUND_Y, WIDTH, GROUND_Y);

  // draw enemy
  ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
  for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(enemies[i].image, enemies[i].pos.x, enemies[i].pos.y, enemies[i].image.width, enemies[i].image.height);
  }
}

// game loop (not important for this question)
const TIMESTEP = 1 / 60;
let accumulator = 0;
let lastRender = 0;

function loop(timestamp) {
  accumulator += (timestamp - lastRender) / 1000;
  lastRender = timestamp;
  while (accumulator >= TIMESTEP) {
    update(TIMESTEP, timestamp);
    accumulator -= TIMESTEP;
  }
  draw();

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jump_Over_It</title>
  <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run this code, the spike’s y position gets messed up (run code to see what I mean). The spike is supposed to be on top of the ground.

I know that it is this:

`this.image.onload = () => {
      this.image.width /= scale;
      this.image.height /= scale;
 }`

part of the code that it is not working, but I do not understand why it is not working. What I am trying to achieve here is to make the images smaller in size. The reason I added `this.image.onload` is because the loading of the image is asynchronous so I have to wait until the image is loaded to change the image width and height.

How can I make this work?

Comment: i think `this` in the context you created is the image itself.  If you used an arrow function then your code may work

Comment: @aaaaaa I changed the function to an arrow function. Now there is no error, but the code doesn’t work as expected :(

Comment: Please reduce this code to the absolute barest [mcve]. That's an important exercise to run through because a) it means you _only_ show code relevant to the problem and b) 99% of the time you actually solve the problem because once you've removed all the bits that are irrelevant (hardcode anything that was dynamic before, remove calls you don't use, etc) you actually spot the problem all on your own. And if you don't, see (a) again.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for the advise, I tried to make my code shorter.

Comment: You have more to remove: there is no need for the animation loop, and no need for the update() function: if this is a problem it's going to be a problem immediately, no need to draw more than a single frame.